# How to create an npm module using typescript for both cjs and esm

Tags: typescript, npm

I want to publish my first npm module which I've written in typescript. I want to generate both `cjs` and `esm` modules (so they work with both `require` and `import`) and also export the type declarations.

Another thing I couldn't figure out is how to make importing my module not require `.default` to access what I actually want to export by default.

I would need some help with configuring `package.json`, `tsconfig.cjs.json` and `tsconfig.esm.json`